# Is it possible to work on localhost but have the upload folder linked remotly for dev?

Tags: remote

I would like to develop my website locally on my computer WAMP server but the thing is that all images and stuff are on the remote server in the uploads folder. Is there a way to work locally for files and link the upload folder to the remote server for media content ? Maybe a vhost setting or something like that.

Comment: this is not wordress specific problem, therefor although some people have already upvoted it, it is off topic. you might get good answers here but you will probably get better on other stack.

Comment: It's wordpress related since I talk about the upload folder of Wordpress to develop on a local machine.

Comment: which is not different from an upload folder in jomla, drupal, or any other framework. But it is your right not to seek better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Paul Clark's [Uploads by Proxy](http://wordpress.org/plugins/uploads-by-proxy/) plugin:

> For local development: Automatically load images from the production version of wp-content/uploads if they are missing locally.

Answer (score 0):

There are tools available to map a remote folder to a local one, but there are a couple of things to watch for with that. One is that even if you have the uploads folder synchronized, your local WordPress media admin won't know they exist since that info is stored in the database.

You would also want to be sure you don't erase any of the files in your local folder or those changes may sync back and break your live site.

If you're on a *nix or OS X machine, look into rsync, or mounting a folder via ssh.

Answer (score 0):

Not answering the question, but a possible solution for someone with a similar problem and just wanting to have placeholder images for their media content: http://placehold.it

I use it a lot during developing stages of a design.